# BTRFS in RAID1 is showing double the disk space

Tags: btrfs

All my GUI programs started showing 16TB total space and 8TB free space available, while it should be 8TB total and 4TB available. Any ideas what went wrong and how to fix it?

My `btrfs` RAID 1 configuration started to show twice as much disk space and free space available, as if my configuration changed to RAID0, but it did not.

I have two identical 8TB disks, I recently upgraded to `5.3.0-46-generic #38~18.04.1-Ubuntu`

My /etc/fstab entry looks like this, where UUID is blkid's UUID of /dev/sda & /dev/sdb:

`UUID=1b962b21-3130-498b-9543-e84c90f12fdf /mountpoint btrfs defaults 0 0`

$ sudo btrfs fi df /mountpoint (this seems OK)

```
Data, RAID1: total=6.43TiB, used=3.58TiB 
Data, single: total=1.00GiB, used=0.00B 
System, RAID1: total=64.00MiB, used=1.12MiB 
Metadata, RAID1: total=9.03GiB, used=5.19GiB 
GlobalReserve, single: total=512.00MiB, used=0.00B
```

$ sudo btrfs fi usage /mountpoint

```
Overall:
    Device size:          14.55TiB
    Device allocated:         12.89TiB
    Device unallocated:        1.66TiB
    Device missing:          0.00B
    Used:              7.17TiB
    Free (estimated):          3.69TiB  (min: 3.69TiB)
    Data ratio:               2.00
    Metadata ratio:           2.00
    Global reserve:      512.00MiB  (used: 0.00B)

Data,single: Size:1.00GiB, Used:0.00B
   /dev/sdb    1.00GiB

Data,RAID1: Size:6.43TiB, Used:3.58TiB
   /dev/sda    6.43TiB
   /dev/sdb    6.43TiB

Metadata,RAID1: Size:9.03GiB, Used:5.19GiB
   /dev/sda    9.03GiB
   /dev/sdb    9.03GiB

System,RAID1: Size:64.00MiB, Used:1.12MiB
   /dev/sda   64.00MiB
   /dev/sdb   64.00MiB

Unallocated:
   /dev/sda  852.97GiB
   /dev/sdb  851.97GiB
```

`$ sudo btrfs device stats` shows no errors for both devices and I just finished full scrub, did not solve my problem. All files are accessible, they don't seem corrupt.

When I go to Nautilus, select all the files on the volume and right-click properties, Contents: totaling shows correct numbers, same as `$ du -h /mountpoint`

**Update**

Output of `$ blkid /dev/sda`

```
/dev/sda: LABEL="B1" UUID="1b962b21-3130-498b-9543-e84c90f12fce" UUID_SUB="58408830-2442-416f-8e6a-e55bfb430764" TYPE="btrfs" PTTYPE="dos"
```

Output of `$ blkid /dev/sdb`

```
/dev/sdb: LABEL="B1" UUID="1b962b21-3130-498b-9543-e84c90f12fce" UUID_SUB="65bd227f-d2c2-4b5b-a73b-a540989c7d41" TYPE="btrfs"
```

Output of `/etc/fstab`

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
UUID=d65dd525-0111-4c6e-a865-b9a912e59e51 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=D7F2-12D3  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0

# mount BTRFS 2 x 8TB RAID1 
UUID=1b962b21-3130-498b-9543-e84c90f12fce /media/user/B1 btrfs defaults 0 0

# mount old test disks
/dev/disk/by-uuid/1b40a350-7573-4f29-aef6-8be2f34cd111 /mnt/1b40a350-7573-4f29-aef6-8be2f34cd111 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-name=TEST2 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/56effa28-df91-4b70-b73e-7665856e829e /mnt/56effa28-df91-4b70-b73e-7665856e829e auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-name=TEST1 0 0
```

About the UUID, I formated both disks few years ago with this command:
`$ sudo mkfs.btrfs -m raid1 -d raid1 /dev/sda /dev/sdb`

And output of `$sudo btrfs fi show` is:

```
Label: 'B1'  uuid: 1b962b21-3130-498b-9543-e84c90f12fce
    Total devices 2 FS bytes used 3.59TiB
    devid    1 size 7.28TiB used 6.44TiB path /dev/sda
    devid    2 size 7.28TiB used 6.45TiB path /dev/sdb
```

So I don't know why, but they have the same uuid.

Comment: Please elaborate `where UUID is blkid's UUID of /dev/sda & /dev/sdb:`. Each disk has its own UUID.

Comment: I think balance should fix it.

Comment: Can you shouw your `fstab`? I suspect you mounted it twice ;-)

Comment: @Pilot6 Hi I updated the question with my `fstab` and few more information that could help.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Balance_Filters and thanks to comments to my questions, `btrfs balance` function was the right answer.

`$sudo btrfs balance start -v -dusage=0 /mountpoint` fixed my problem.

Output:

```
Dumping filters: flags 0x1, state 0x0, force is off
  DATA (flags 0x2): balancing, usage=0
Done, had to relocate 1 out of 6603 chunks
```

After that, free space is again displayed correctly.